# GAC dll cannot be uninstalled

Tags: .net, gac, global-assembly-cache

I am trying to uninstall a **dll** out of my **GAC** but I cannot do so.

When I run the following command `gacutil -u AssemblyName`, I am getting the error message:
`The assembly is for atleast one application required`.
(translated from my original german message that says: `Die Assembly ist für mindestens eine Anwendung erforderlich`.)

How can I figure out what application is blocking my uninstall, I have already uninstalled everything that seems logic to me.
Maybe there is some registry entry still laying around or some stuff?!?

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873195) article you have to go look in these keys

• HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Assemblies\Global
• HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global

You have to look in those keys for REG_MULTI_SZ entry that resembles the following:

```
=ysgSC6wx9uiD1dqmmjW>m$!GP^D'A@?z}gn3}lta
```

and if you find one, remove the complete entry

for your convienance you can run thse two commands to find if you have keys that fullfill that criteria:

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Assemblies\Global /v /f "YourAssembly*"
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global /v /f "YourAssembly*"
```

Output you will see for example for assembly EntityFramework*:

> EntityFramework,version="4.1.0.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="B77A5C56
>   1934E089",processorArchitecture="MSIL"    REG_MULTI_SZ
>   nRfmTp.Na@?e!bFXjH]yMa in>'J*rOm2_)=0&Rea1c^?{